# Base64 encoding in 12C BPEL is replacing the parent tag by the BPEL variable name

Tags: base64, bpel, encoder-decoder, bpelxexec

I'm trying to base64 encode a request XML by storing it first in a BPEL varible.
Could you please have a look at the problem and suggest me what I did wrong and how the same can be fixed?

e.g. When I decode the encoded message, I get the output  as

```
<varName ns0="namespace">
</varName>
```

instead of

```
<ns0:input ns0="namespace">
</ns0:input>
```

The base64 code is as below -

```
try{
    oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement inputPayload = (oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLElement)getVariableData("varName");
    oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDocument xmlPayload = inputPayload.getDocument();
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    xmlPayload.print(outputStream);
    java.lang.String xml_output = outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
    xml_output =  xml_output.substring(12, xml_output.length()-14);
    java.lang.String xml_oneLine = xml_output.replaceAll("\\s*[\\r\\n]+\\s*", "").trim();
    xml_oneLine = xml_oneLine.replaceAll("(^\\h*)|(\\h*$)","").trim();
    java.lang.String xml_encoded = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +xml_oneLine;
    oracle.soa.common.util.Base64Encoder encoder = new oracle.soa.common.util.Base64Encoder();
    java.lang.String encodedString = null;
    encodedString = encoder.encode(xml_encoded.trim());
    setVariableData("outputVariableName", "requestVariableName", "XPath", encodedString);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Kind Regards,
Jaihind

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with base64 encoding but was with the type of variable.
The variable was of anySimpleType type but when it was changed to the type of XML element then the issue got resolved.

-Jaihind